# Yandex MAP KIT. При перемещение камеры карты ппроверять вхождение в полигон центра камеры

Tags: kotlin, yandex-maps-api, yandexmapkit, mapkit

Здрасте язык Котлин среда АС, апи Яндекс Мапкит
Хочу сделать также - [Видос с реализацией](https://youtu.be/ihdjnG4H2zc?si=Gd5xUb4QcICRwDBy)

Есть полигон, и я получаю координаты центра камеры на экране телефона.

Одну реализацию у меня полчилось сделать, это повесить слушатель нажатий на сам полигон, и работает это как нужно.

```
val tapListener = object : MapObjectTapListener {
    override fun onMapObjectTap(p0: MapObject, p1: Point): Boolean {
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "В зоне" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        return true
    }

}
```

polygonMapObject.addTapListener(tapListener)

Но мне нужно чтобы это работало не от тапов, а от перемещения камеры карты

Из моих мыслей, возможно ли проверить вхождение координаты в область полигона, чтобы я получал булеву функцию средствами MapKit?

Или возможно ли с эмулировать нажатие на экран посредством нажатия на View обьект на экране?

Comment: Релизнул эту шнягу обычной функцией трассировки луча, мне спасибо всем пока